# Replacing keyword in a string php with case sensitive behaviour

Tags: php, regex

What function of Php would allow replacing the search keyword within a string? Let say we have a string "Hello! How are you?" and if someone searches "how" will present this complete string with some replacement as: Hello! **How** are you?

```
Hello! <b>How</b> are you?
```

I tried with str_replace, though it is case sensitive so surely wouldn't work. Then I tried str_ireplace and it worked but the issue is in replacement it replaced it with all small characters. Here is a snippet of code:

```
$myString = "Hello! How are you?";
$toSearch = "how";
$newString = str_ireplace($toSearch, '<b>'.$toString.'</b>', $myString);
```

It resulted in: Hello! **how** are you?

```
Hello! <b>how</b> are you?
```

I hope this should not be as tricky as it looks like. One of it is in our browser:

[image]

Comment: You are looking for [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$myString = "Hello! How are you?";
$toSearch = "how";

// Build a regex from $toSearch
$re = '/'.preg_quote($toSearch, '/').'/i';       // i == ignore case

// Use $re to search, replace each matching substring
// with itself surrounded by <b> and </b>
$newString = preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $myString);
```

If you need to find only full words then you can use:

```
$re = '/\b'.preg_quote($toSearch, '\b/').'/i';
```

Read more about [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) and [PCRE patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) and [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: Great! I found it a bit difficult to understand regex many times. And yes the preg_quote() PHP manual has this functionality listed in one of its examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newString = str_ireplace($toSearch, '<b>'.ucwords($toString).'</b>', $myString);
```

is this what you wanted?

The above code will replace the keyword with a capitalised word

Comment: I think it needs to be aware of the word it's replacing rather than do `ucwords()` on everything.

Comment: Yes ucwords will always capitalise word. Though the search could be for any word in between. Like ‘Are’